# Filter the words that in the same sentence with other words python

Tags: python, nlp

I have a dataframe, df, in the following form:

```
df = 
index   Text 
----------------
0       My name is George and I don't like football 
1       Hey find me on instagram to play basketball 
2       I am down for Saturday night
...
1000    text1000
```

I have also one more list which contains some key words, the name of this list is,

```
key_word = [football, basketball, tennis]
```

I have also one another list which contains some usernames, like

```
usernames = [instagram, facebook, snapchat]
```

I want to find the usernames that are in the same sentence of dataframe, df, with the key words, key_words.

In my example the output should be the following list

```
output = [instagram]
```

Comment: A full example  should be better to get an idea of your problem

Comment: @Dani Mesejo Nice idea, sorry for that. I added an example. Hope that this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach using [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
key_words = ["football", "basketball", "tennis"]
usernames = ["instagram", "facebook", "snapchat"]

# create a boolean mask that contains the key_words and the usernames
mask = df["Text"].str.contains("|".join(key_words)) & df["Text"].str.contains("|".join(usernames))

# extract the usernames from those rows that contains both usernames and key_words
res = df.loc[mask, "Text"].str.extract(f'({"|".join(usernames)})')
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
           0
1  instagram
```

The expression:

```
"|".join(key_words) # key_words can be any list of strings
```

creates a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) that will match a string that contains any of strings in the list.

For creating really efficient regular expressions for this type of problem see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69635362/speed-up-millions-of-regex-replacements-in-dataframe).