# What is the time complexity of this JS algorithm

Tags: javascript, regex, performance, time-complexity

IsUnique: Implement an algorithm to determine if a string has all unique characters.

In one of my version, I'm using RegExp. Can anyone please explain to me what is the time complexity of this algorithm and why?

```
const isUniqueV2 = function isUniqueV2(str) {
  const cleanStr = str.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9]/g, '');
  const strlen = cleanStr.length;
  if(!strlen) return false;
  const reg = new RegExp(/(.)[^\1]*?\1/g);
  if(reg.test(cleanStr)) return false;
  return true;
}
```

Time Complexity of a RegExp varies with the implementation. I have a version with O(N). I just want to know will this one performs better than the one using dictionary O(N)?

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Whatever you're doing it's o[1], you're not looping over any elements but i'm not sure about how the RegExp works, it has to do some looping but i'm sure it's efficient shouldn't be more than o[n] if n is the length of the str

Comment: @OmarMneimneh Even though the pattern will require the engine to iterate over each character a number of times proportional to the length of the string? Worst-case, it'd require something around `0.5 * L^2` steps

Comment: @Andreas I have solved this problem is 4 versions. I have a clear idea about the rest of the solutions time complexities but as in this version I used Regex I get confused. I don't have any idea how to calculate time complexity for RegExp.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the complexity of regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378455/what-is-the-complexity-of-regular-expression)

Comment: @CertainPerformance so you mean it can exceed o[n]? I wasn't concerned about the RegExp because I don't think a String is usually large, that's why i didn't take it into consideration, to be honest i don't know how the RegExp validation works

Comment: @OmarMneimneh I'm not sure on the terminology, but the *number of steps* is `O(N^2)`, where `N` is the length of the input string. If one considers RE engine steps to correspond to an algorithm's time complexity, then yeah, it'd be `O(N^2)` overall

Comment: I'm fairly sure it's linear. We have `toLowerCase()` which is O(n), and we have `replace()` which is O(n), and `test()` which is also also O(n). I don't see anything that would be O(n^2)...

Comment: @CertainPerformance I tried to make my expression non-greedy that why added the '?' quantifier. I think otherwise the regex engine has to do more work.

Comment: @sushobhan If the number of steps is the factor you're interested in, lazy quantifiers usually make a pattern take *longer* time to complete, not shorter, because after each character the engine has to check to see if the rest of the pattern matches before forward-tracking. Compare [`.*?x`](https://regex101.com/r/dLQ9N9/1) (15 steps) against `.*x` (4 steps)

Comment: @CertainPerformance Oh, I didn't know that. I thought non-greedy approach runs faster than greedy approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, in the worst-case, the time complexity of the algorithm will be `O(N)`, but *why* it's `O(N)` is a bit complicated. There are three operations to consider.

First, the `toLowerCase()` on the input string. This is `O(N)` with respect to the string's length, easy.

Second, the first `.replace` function: `.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/g, '')`. This is also `O(N)` - iterate through all characters, and replace non-alphanumeric characters with the empty string.

Third, and most complicated: the `/(.)[^\1]*?\1/g` test. Let's [break down](https://regex101.com/r/LJqtHn/1) this regular expression first. Note that `\1` inside a *character set* probably doesn't do what you think it is - it's not a backreference, it matches the unicode character at index 1, which is the [Start of Heading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#SOH) control character:

```js
console.log(/[\1]/.test(String.fromCharCode(1)));
console.log(String.fromCharCode(1));
// not the sort of thing that would appear in an ordinary string, as you can see
```

That's not what you want. Let's fix that, for the sake of simplicity - it won't make any difference for your algorithm's complexity, so let's assume we're using the pattern `/(.).*?\1/` instead.

It will capture the first character in a group, then lazy-repeat any character, trying to find the character matched by the first group again. The regex engine will attempt this test starting at the first character in the string - if the string length is `N`, it will start at index `0` and iterate over indicies `0` to `N - 1`, checking whether any characters match the character at index `0`. Since we're assuming the worst-case, we can assume that this will fail (no duplicates of the first character found), and we've carried out about N operations. Then, the engine will try to match starting at the *next* index, index `1`, and will iterate over each following character until it gets to the end of the string (`N - 1`), looking for the same character matched at index 1. Worst-case, this will fail, we've just carried out around `N - 1` operations, and the engine will forward-track *another* character, to index 2. See the pattern?

```
Starting index     ~Operations required to check this index    ~Total operations
0                  N                                           N
1                  N-1                                         2N-1
2                  N-2                                         3N-3
3                  N-3                                         4N-6
4                  N-4                                         5N-10
...
N-1                1                                           N^2 - 0.5N^2
```

Worst-case, there are no duplicate characters in the string, and the engine takes around `0.5N^2` steps to carry out the entire `.test` function. This isn't exact because there's some [overhead](https://regex101.com/r/SgXm6o/2/debugger) related to matching the captured character, but it's insignificant compared to the `N^2` factor. Try it out on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SgXm6o/2/) - you can see that an input of 62 alphanumeric characters takes 2203 steps, which isn't that far from `0.5 * 62^2 = 1922`.

So, because this `.test` function has `O(N^2)` complexity in the worst case, it would sound like the algorithm as a whole has `O(N^2)` complexity, right? Actually, no! The reason is that the first `.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/g, '')` ensures that the string being tested will contain *only* lower-case letters and digits (36 possible characters). This means that the `.test` can only iterate over a maximum of 36 characters before returning `true` - a 37th character (or any character after that) will *necessarily* be a duplicate of one of the previous characters, because there are only 36 possible unique characters. The worst-case string would look something like

```
0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz...
```

which would require around `36N` steps to get to the `z`s, find that they're duplicated, and pass the `.test`. So, the worst case for the `.test`, *given the constrained input*, is actually `O(N)`, not `O(N^2)`!

To sum up: the `toLowerCase()` is `O(N)` in the worst-case. The `.replace` is `O(N)` in the worst case. Finally, the `.test` is `O(N)` in the worst case. So, your function's time complexity is `O(N)` in the worst case.

All that said, although it may be `O(N)`, it's still relatively inefficient compared to your [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53720449/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-this-js-algorithm#answer-53720729) implementation, which iterates over each character in the string and adds it as a property of an object, returning `true` once any duplicate character is found.