# Regex - Match any word but ignore specific word

Tags: regex

I want to match any word that starts/ends or not contain with word "end" but ignore word "end", for example:

- hello - would match
- boyfriend - would match
- endless - would match
- endend - would match

but

- end - would **NOT** match

I'm using `^(?!end)).*$` but its not what I want.

Sorry for my english

Comment: Wait. You just want to exclude the word 'end' itself? All the rest should match?

Comment: yes sir, is this possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
^(?!(end)$).+$
```

This will match everything except end.

Comment: Just a modification. You should use `.+` instead of `.*`. Because `.*` will match zero width.

Comment: @Rahul good point.. thanks for notifying

Comment: @downvoter a reason would be nice.

Comment: Huge ! And if you want 2 word excluded ==> ^(?!(word1|word2)$).+$

Answer (score 0):

So you want to match any word, but not "end" ?

Unless I'm misunderstanding, a conditional statement is everything that is needed... In pseudocode:

```
if (word != "end") {
    // Match
}
```

If you want to match all the words in a *text* that are not "end" you could just remove all the non-alpha characters, replace pattern `(^end | end | end$)` by an empty string, and then do a string split.
The other answers with a single regex might be better then, because [regex matches are O(n)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892115/whats-the-time-complexity-of-average-regex-algorithms), no matter of the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `\b(?!(?:end\b))[\w]+`

Components: 
`\b` -> Start of the word boundary for each words.
`(?!` Negative lookahead to eliminate the word **end**.
`(?:end\b)` Non capturing parenthesis with the word end and word boundary. 
`)` Closing tag for negative lookahead.
`[\w]+` character class to capture words.

Explanation: The regex search will only look for locations starting with word boundaries, and will remove matches with end as only word. i.e `[WORD BOUNDARY]end[END OF WORD BOUNDARY]`. `\w` will capture rest of the word. You can keep incrementing this character class if you wish to capture some special characters like `$` etc.