# Exponential running time for simple Python regex

Tags: python, python-re

In the case of this simple regex

```py
pattern = re.compile(r"(.*)*A")
```

which is immediately compiled, the search time grows exponentially with string length. Is this an expected behavior of python's `re` library? I would expect that applying a compiled regex on a string should result in linear performance in string length.

```py
pattern.search("x"*23)
```

1 second.

```py
pattern.search("x"*24)
```

2 seconds.

```py
pattern.search("x"*25)
```

4 seconds.

etc.

I tried both py3.7 and 3.8 and even 2.7, same results. However, I couldn't see this problem in applying the same regex from command line in sed.

Comment: @superbrain One might expect linear performance because it's possible, and well-known to be possible; any (true) regex can be compiled to a DFA which can be used to recognise the pattern in linear time.

Comment: @kaya3 So now I'm reading about it, but am still surprised that people use python so much, and nobody cares... I came to this question while debugging a real regex that simply never terminates.

Comment: Just for reference: it seems that the `regex` library https://pypi.org/project/regex/ is compatible with `re` and does not suffer from this catastrophic backtracking -- at least no in simple examples I tried.